# Can we get an expandable HTML tree of an element in Mozilla console?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Using Chrome, when I type `console.log(document.body)` in the console and press enter, I get an HTML tree (or hierarchy) of the current page. For example, on [google.com](https://www.google.com/), I get the following

[image]

**Figure 1.** Output of `console.log(document.body)` on Chrome.

However, when I use Mozilla, I get an object description with all the properties like below.

[image]

**Figure 2.** Output of `console.log(document.body)` on Mozilla.

When you use `console.dir(document.body)` on Chrome, it produces an output like **Figure.2**, but on Mozilla, the output is the same as **Figure.1**.

Is it possible to get something like **Figure.1** on Mozilla?

Comment: `console.log(document.body.outerHTML);`

Comment: @ScottMarcus: It is not exactly the same as **Figure.1**. I would like to expand the tags and see the child nodes but `console.log(document.body.outerHTML)` gives a string.

Comment: What if you scroll down to the `innerHTML` property of the second example and expand it.  Doesn't that show you the same thing?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: That's messy too and does not give the HTML hierarchy in an expandable way.